# How to disable mail search in tracker-needle?

Tags: desktop, search, file-search

I wish to search only my local folders. Everything was ok, until I installed thunderbird and downloaded mail.

Now searches take too much time, because tracker searches the mail to.

Where in the interface the option to switch off the mail search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an "TrackerBird 1.0.2" addon in thunderbird. It just need to be disabled.